# Position text inside a element with fixed height

Tags: css

When I make a badge/button etc in css. I usually position the text inside the element using padding. I have now come across a situation where this doesn't work.

The p-tag has the height 50px. This means that if I add padding the total height will be to large. Is there some other way of changing the texts position inside the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to move text vertically or horizontally? If horizontally you can use text-indent.

If you want to position the text in the vertical center of your container and you only have one line of text you can set the line-height property to be the same as the height of the element.

Provide exact details or code sample and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use height, you can use something like below to get this right:

```
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:16px 33px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/ASzEf/2/)